# SQLAlchemy/Pyramid DBSession refresh issue

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Here's my scenario:
First view renders form, data goes to secend view, where i store it in DB (MySQL) and redirects to third view which shows what was written to db:

```
Stoing to db:
    DBSession.add(object)
    transaction.commit()

DB Session:
    DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False,
                                            autocommit=False, 
                                            extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

After that when I refresh my page several time sometimes I can see DB change, sometimes not, one time old data, second time new and so on...
When I restart server (locally, pserve) DB data is up-to-date.

Maybe it's a matter of creating session?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show where exactly is the DBSession variable defined and how you redirect from the second view to the third? You can also provide a rough outline of your view functions as well

Answer (score 1):

Check MySQL's [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html).

The default for InnoDB is `REPEATABLE READ`: "All consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first read."

You can specify the isolation level in the call to `create_engine`. See the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#transaction-isolation-level).

I suggest you try the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help - the same issue after saving to db and redirect - one time when i refresh i have new data, second time old, after few refreshes it "stabilizes"

Comment: Hmm. The only other thing I can think of is the ``ZopeTransactionExtension``. I'm not sure of what it does, could you try without it?

Comment: ZopeTransactionExtension makes sure every session that opens joins an active transaction, and without it it's the same.

Comment: Maybe it's a an issue with redirect with HTTPFound?

Comment: I tried postgres - the same, weird that this problem is not global, maybe I look at wrong part of code...

Comment: I've never used ZopeTransactionExtension. The way I normally use a SQLAlchemy session is: ``DBSession.add(...); DBSession.commit()``

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what your transaction object is or how it connects to the SQLAlchemy database session. I couldn't see anything about transactions in the Pyramid docs and I don't see anything in your code that links your transaction object to your SQLAlchemy session so maybe there is some configuration missing. What example are you basing this code on?

Also: the `sessionmaker` call is normally done at file score to create a single session factory, which is then used repeatedly to create session objects from the same source. ["the sessionmaker() function is normally used to create a top level Session configuration which can then be used throughout an application without the need to repeat the configurational arguments."](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#getting-a-session)

It may be the case that since you are creating multiple session factories that there is some data that is supposed to be shared across sessions but is actually not shared because it is created once per factory. Try [just calling sessionmaker once](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#session-frequently-asked-questions) and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is likely to be a persistent session. By default, Pyramids expires all objects in the session after a commit -- this means that SQLA will fetch them from the database the next time you want them, and they will be fresh.

You have overridden this default by indicating "expire_on_commit=False" -- so, make sure that after committing a change you call session.expire_all() if you intend for that session object to grab fresh data on subsequent requests. (The session object is the same for multiple requests in Pyramid, but you aren't guaranteed to get the same thread-scoped session) I recommend not setting expire on commit to false, or using a non-global session: see http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/database/sqlalchemy.html#using-a-non-global-session

Alternatively, you could make sure you are expiring objects when necessary, knowing that unexpired objects will stay in memory the way they are and will not be refreshed, and may differ from the same object in a different thread-scoped session.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're setting `expire_on_commit=False`. If you remove that, it should work. You can read more about what it does on http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit